# how to install old version php 5.3.26 on centos 6.5

Tags: php, apache, centos6

Can anyone provide me a guide to install old version of php 5.3.26 on centos 6.5? 
I have installed httpd through yum install -y httpd.

Comment: You should state such questions on ServerFault, not StackOverflow

Comment: PHP 5.3 is in [End of Life](http://php.net/eol.php). You should consider a later version of PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go there :

https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.3.26

- Download as zip.
- Unzip on your server.
- Now, configure your PHP.  This is where you customize your PHP
  with various options, like which extensions will be enabled.  Do a
  ./configure --help for a list of available options.  In our example
  we'll do a simple configure with Apache 1 and MySQL support.  Your
  path to apxs may differ from our example.

  ./configure --with-mysql --with-apxs=/www/bin/apxs
- And compile : `make && make install`

There are plenty of informations about this in the `INSTALL` file in the folder you unzipped